# Set the values of heatmap in highCharts in javascript function

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using higharts HeatMap. I am referring this link http://www.highcharts.com/demo/heatmap for heat Map.

I want to change the value of heatMap in JavaScript function. I have tried the below code. but values are not changed.

```
function check()
{
     alert("check called");
     alert("values"+ heat.getValueAt({ x: 0, y: 0 }));
     heat.series.setData([0, 0, 12]);// heat is instance of heat Map
     alert("after");        
}
```

complete code is

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Chart</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/heatmap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var heat;
    $(function () {

    heat = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
               renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'heatmap',
            marginTop: 40,
            marginBottom: 80
    },

    title: {
            text: 'Usage '
    },

    xAxis: {
            categories: ['Alexander', 'Marie', 'Maximilian', 'Sophia', 'Lukas', 'Maria', 'Leon', 'Anna', 'Tim', 'Laura']
    },

    yAxis: {
            categories: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'],
            title: null
    },

    colorAxis: {
            min: 0,
            minColor: '#5858FA',
            maxColor: '#FF0000'
    },

    legend: {
            align: 'right',
            layout: 'vertical',
            margin: 0,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y:5,
            symbolHeight: 280
    },

    tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.series.xAxis.categories[this.point.x] + '</b> sold <br><b>' +
                    this.point.value + '</b> items on <br><b>' + this.series.yAxis.categories[this.point.y] + '</b>';
    }
    },

    series: [{
            name: 'Sales per employee',
            borderWidth: 0,
            data: [[0, 0, 2], [0, 1, 4], [0, 2, 6], [0, 3, 8], [0, 4, 10], [1, 0, 12], [1, 1, 14], [1, 2, 15], [1, 3, 25], [1, 4, 24], [2, 0, 23], [2, 1, 15], [2, 2, 25], [2, 3, 15], [2, 4, 10], [3, 0, 20], [3, 1, 13], [3, 2, 14], [3, 3, 15], [3, 4, 16], [4, 0, 13], [4, 1, 5], [4, 2, 8], [4, 3, 10], [4, 4, 15], [5, 0, 8], [5, 1, 22], [5, 2, 12], [5, 3, 6], [5, 4, 10], [6, 0, 13], [6, 1, 9], [6, 2, 8], [6, 3, 9], [6, 4, 6], [7, 0, 13], [7, 1, 1], [7, 2, 12], [7, 3, 33], [7, 4, 30], [8, 0, 25], [8, 1, 17], [8, 2, 23], [8, 3, 24], [8, 4, 20], [9, 0, 18], [9, 1, 14], [9, 2, 11], [9, 3, 18], [9, 4, 11]],
            dataLabels: {

    }
    }]

    });
    });
    function check()
    {
       alert("check called");
      alert("values"+ heat.getValueAt({ x: 0, y: 0 }));
       heat.series.setData([0, 0, 12]);

       alert("after");

    } 

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
<script>check()</script>
<div id="container" style="height: 320px; width: 1000px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to refer to particual serie, as a result it should be heat.series[0].setData()

Comment: I tried with heat.series[0].setData()  also but still the data is not been changed.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is called before your DOM is loaded, so you need to call this in `$(function() {});` or in chart callback.

```
heat = new Highcharts.Chart({
   //chart options  
},function(chart){
     check() 
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/t8suqfku/5/

Answer (score 0):

Heat Map instance should be declared globally so that its  accessible to javascrip function and values for Hea tMap can be changed.